# Using collectstatic with multiple environments

Tags: django, heroku, amazon-s3

I have a Django app on Heroku, with staging and production environments. Static files are hosted on S3. I'm streamlining my deployment process and plan to set up fabfiles once I have things working manually.

How can I configure collectstatic to push to multiple places? If I run it locally, it uses my dev settings (with a local STATIC_ROOT). If I run it on one of my Heroku apps (heroku run ./manage.py collectstatic), then it can't grab the files (since .slugignore ensures they're never pushed to Heroku). The same applies if I include collectstatic in my Procfile.

I'm also using django-pipeline, though it's not yet doing much since I'm stuck on the collectstatic bit.

**UPDATE**
In response to Marat's question, I tried passing a settings file as an option to collectstatic: `./manage.py collectstatic --settings=project.settings.prod`, but got an error: `Unknown command: 'collectstatic'` I checked on the server though and Installed Apps does include django.contrib.staticfiles and I can also run collectstatic remotely, so I'm not sure what would cause that.

Answer (score 2):

You can set the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE so you don't need specify --settings everywhere:

```
heroku config:set DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=project.settings.prod
```

Comment: Priceless. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

First, if you are going to serve static via CloudFront, you can use custom origin and always use local STATIC_ROOT. Actually it has some advantages over S3 source, eg gzip support.

Another good thing you can do is to have environment dependent settings in a separate file and then import it in settings.py, eg:

local_settings.py (not in project repository, yet you can have local_settings.py.example):

```
#environment dependent settings
DATABASES = { .. }
CACHES = { .. }
STATIC_ROOT = 'your_path/static'
```

settings.py:

```
import local_settings
```

Comment: I'm planning to set up CloudFront but haven't yet - does the gzip support achieve something different than the django middleware (django.middleware.gzip.GZipMiddleware)?

Answer (score 0):

I've just replied a similar question on [Upload Media from Heroku to Amazon S3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13214507/upload-media-from-heroku-to-amazon-s3/14437249#14437249). If you customise your settings to take in account environmental vars, you can use filesystem storage backends locally and S3 storage backends when pushing to Heroku. This will collect and upload your static files when your slug is compiled.