# Upload Media from Heroku to Amazon S3

Tags: python, django, heroku, amazon-s3

New to Heroku & Amazon S3, so bear with me. Uploaded my Django app onto Heroku, and having a problem with user media uploads. The model is below:

```
#models.py
class Movie(models.Model):
    title           = models.CharField(max_length = 500)
    poster          = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'storages.backends.s3boto')
    pub_date        = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    author          = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

The poster attribute is the one where the image is uploaded. I had it running fine locally, and now on Heroku there is an error. So I added 'storages.backends.s3boto', as numerous other posts have told me to. (not sure if right).

My Settings.py file looks like this right now, kind of a mess:

```
#settings.py
PROJECT_ROOT   = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
PROJECT_DIR    = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, '../qanda')

DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE    = 'storages.backends.s3boto.S3BotoStorage'
STATICFILES_STORAGE     = 'storages.backends.s3boto.S3BotoStorage'

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID         = '****************'
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY     = '************'
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME   = 'mrt-assets'
AWS_PRELOAD_METADATA      = True

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'qanda/media/movie_posters/)
MEDIA_URL = '/media'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'staticfiles')
STATIC_URL = 'https://mrt-assets.s3.amazonaws.com/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'static'),)
```

My bucket is called mrt-assets, and there are 2 folders in there static (css, js, images and media. I'm not too worried about the static files for now, as I've hardcoded the CSS/JS files into my HTML files*, but how do I get my user uploaded media (images of any kind) into mrt-assets/media?

*although if someone wanted to help with STATIC files too that would be great. But user uploaded media more urgent.

EDIT (per Yuji's comment):

Have tried a number of options, and none of them working. I've gone back and deleted a lot of changes, and this is now my Settings

```
#settings.py
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
MEDIA_ROOT = 'http://s3.amazonaws.com/mrt-assets/media/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
STATIC_ROOT = 'http://s3.amazonaws.com/mrt-assets/static/'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = STATIC_URL + 'admin/'
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, "templates"),)

#models.py
#same as before, but now have changed the poster directory
poster = models.ImageField().
```

Not really sure what to do, need to connect my Heroku app to S3 so user media uploads are saved there.

Have now changed my S3 Bucket to this

```
mrt-assets
    static
        css
        js
        images
    media
        (empty)
```

Comment: Chris, what is the error? I had issues with a particular S3Boto and had to revert to an older version for Heroku

Comment: Yuji, will edit question to fill in on current status. Thanks in advance!

Comment: tried using [link](https://github.com/jamstooks/django-s3-folder-storage) Django s3 folder storage. followed the instructions in git, added to INSTALLED_APPS tuple, added to requirements.txt, but got error s3 folder storage.

Comment: Chris, I still don't see an error message. What is the python stack trace you're getting when there is an error? For future reference, this is extremely important to post when asking a question about an error.

Answer (score 5):

The trick of getting your media to upload into `<bucket>/media` and your static assets into `<bucket>/static` is to create two different default storage backends for the two asset types or to explicitly instantiate your model fields with a storage object taking a `location` parameter.

## Instantiating model field with custom storage

```
from storages.backends.s3boto import S3BotoStorage

class Movie(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    poster = models.ImageField(storage=S3BotoStorage(location='media'))
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

Giving `S3BotoStorage` a `location` will prefix all uploads with its path.

## Creating custom storage backends for media and static assets

This is almost the same as explicitly defining a storage backend with
location, but instead we'll be using `settings.MEDIA_ROOT` and
`settings.STATIC_ROOT` to apply a path prefix globally.

```
# settings.py
STATIC_ROOT = '/static/'
MEDIA_ROOT  = '/media/'

DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'app.storage.S3MediaStorage'
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'app.storage.S3StaticStorage'


# app/storage.py
from django.conf import settings
from storages.backends.s3boto import S3BotoStorage

class S3MediaStorage(S3BotoStorage):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        kwargs['location'] = kwargs.get('location', 
            settings.MEDIA_ROOT.replace('/', ''))
        super(S3MediaStorage, self).__init__(**kwargs)

class S3StaticStorage(S3BotoStorage):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        kwargs['location'] = kwargs.get('location', 
            settings.STATIC_ROOT.replace('/', ''))
        super(S3StaticStorage, self).__init__(**kwargs)
```

## Refining it

You can refine the above code to take advantage of
[Heroku config vars](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars#using-foreman)
to make it more portable:

```
# settings.py
import os
STATIC_ROOT = os.environ.get('STATIC_ROOT',
    os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'static'))

MEDIA_ROOT = os.environ.get('MEDIA_ROOT',
    os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'media'))

DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = os.environ.get('DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE', 
    'django.core.files.storage.FileSystemStorage')

STATICFILES_STORAGE = os.environ.get('STATICFILES_STORAGE', 
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.storage.StaticFilesStorage')
```

Couple the above settings with a `.env` file and you can use the
default storage backends locally for development and testing and when
deploying on Heroku you'll automatically switch to
`app.storage.S3MediaStorage` and `app.storage.S3StaticStorage` respectively:

```
# .env
STATIC_ROOT=static
MEDIA_ROOT=media
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE=app.storage.S3MediaStorage
STATICFILES_STORAGE=app.storage.S3StaticStorage
```